# Android M Webview (with multiwindow support enabled) not opening anchor tag when link type is "noreferrer"

Tags: android, android-webview, anchor

I have a webview which loads a website which contains some anchor tag. This anchor tag has the type of "noreferrer" and opens a page in new tab (using target = "_blank"). Now the issue is when I don't enable multi-window support in webview, it works fine on all devices.

But when I enable multi-window support it doesn't work in Marshmallow device but It works fine in all other devices. I have created a [demo project](https://gitlab.com/ankit_aggarwal/test/tree/master) to reproduce it. It works fine in all cases when I remove rel="noreferrer" from anchor tag.

**My Activity code is here**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout mContainer;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private WebView mNewWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                mNewWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
                mNewWebView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ));

                WebSettings webSettings = mNewWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

                mNewWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        view.clearHistory();
                    }
                });
                mContainer.addView(mNewWebView);

                ((WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj).setWebView(mNewWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();

                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mWebView.loadData("<a href=\"https://example.com\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\">open new window</a>",
            "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNewWebView != null) {
            if (mNewWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mNewWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                mNewWebView.destroy();
                mContainer.removeViewAt(1);
                mNewWebView = null;
            }
        } else if (mWebView != null && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.treebo.test.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Few pointers:**

- Multi-window support is enabled using webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true). I am doing this one the webview defined a the layout file.
- When I click the anchor, it opens a new page and onCreateWindow() is called where I create a new webview and add it in view hierarchy.

**Edit 1**

Observed the same issue on android 5.0.2

**Edit 2**

Some clarification on this: I have some use case which opens a web page in a separate tab in the browser (basically payment related page). When I run the same website in the web view, it opens the new tab in same web view (which I don't want. I want to open it in the new web view). That is why I am using multiwindow support. Hope it clears why I am using multiwindow support.

Comment: Pro tips for posting: there's no need to tell us how long you've been stuck (it doesn't get faster answers), nor that you could not find anything to solve it (if you solved it, you would not ask), nor explicit requests for help (that is probably why you are here). Keep it short and succinct if you can - too much chat can dissuade people from reading.

Comment: Thanks. Will take care of these things next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You say

> This anchor tag has the type of "noreferrer" and opens a page in new tab (using target = "_blank").

Is that a HTML tag? Are you trying to open a new HTML page or a new fragement in android? Because I don't understand what you mean with it?

You can find more info about Multi-Window Support for api level 23 or lower here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#testing

> If your app targets API level 23 or lower
>   If your app targets API level 23 or lower and the user attempts to use the app in multi-window mode, the system forcibly resizes the app unless the app declares a fixed orientation.
>
> If your app does not declare a fixed orientation, you should launch
>   your app on a device running Android 7.0 or higher and attempt to put
>   the app in split-screen mode. Verify that the user experience is
>   acceptable when the app is forcibly resized.
>
> If the app declares a fixed orientation, you should attempt to put the
>   app in multi-window mode. Verify that when you do so, the app remains
>   in full-screen mode

Comment: First of all, ask questions in comments and not in the answers section. You can check the project link attached. I am not opening any fragment or activity. The Html page has an anchor tag which has this attribute rel="noreferrer". On click of this anchor tag, it opens a new html page in new tab. By default the new page opens up in same webview. But to open it in new webview, we have to enable multiwindow support.

Comment: Your question was not clear to me. I use my self multiple html page in webview and I don't use multiwindow support for it and it works perfect for me. Instead of rel="norefferrer" . Add a extra class to it. And do in javascript instead then you will have no problems.

Comment: do you understand what "_blank" does in html anchor tag? I have some use case which opens a web page in a separate tab in the browser (basically payment related page). When I run the same website in the web view, it opens the new tab in same web view (which I don't want. I want to open it in the new web view). That is why I am using multiwindow support. Hope it will clear the question.

Comment: I know what that is. I don't enabled multiwindowsupport. But I open a new new page that is a new window with JS 'window.open('localStorage.html');'. Maybe solve it with that? I tried it, it works for android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Comment: you are correct that it will work that way and I have already told that in my question. But my requirement is different and I have mentioned that several times. I am using multiwindow support because I want to open a new window (don't want to load the content in same webview basically). Hope that clear it more :)

Comment: Also, could you tell me which part of the question is not clear?

Comment: Yes know I understand what you want with multiwindow support it means like a splitscreen of 2 windows of your app. Do you have **If your app targets API level 23 or lower and the user attempts to use the app in multi-window mode, the system forcibly resizes the app unless the app declares a fixed orientation.**

Comment: dude, sorry I can't explain more :( Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows(boolean) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onCreateWindow(android.webkit.WebView, boolean, boolean, android.os.Message)

Comment: Its not multi window support which came in android N. Its for webview